# How can I redirect current page to post response with guzzle (laravel)

Tags: laravel, guzzle

For example, I have a form:

```
<form method='post' action='https://test.com'>
<input name='name' value='test'>
<button name='test' type='submit'> </button>
</form>
```

And after submit this redirects me to another page.
My question is 'how can I do the same thing with guzzle  from a controller?' I tried to make:

```
$client =         $client = new GuzzleHttpClient();
$response = $client->post('https://test.com', 
form_params => [
    'name' => 'test'
]);
return $response->getBody()->read(1024);
```

And here I am getting a response that I wanted. but I want to redirect my current page to page with the response.

Answer (score 0):

Use `return redirect()->back()` in method controller

Comment: Maybe add `->withInput()` at the end and use `<input type="text" name="my_field" value="{{ old('my_field') }}">` in the form to refill the inputs with submitted data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try something like this

```
 $client = $client = new GuzzleHttpClient();
 $response = $client->post('https://test.com', 
 form_params => [
  'name' => 'test'
]);
$response_to_return = $response->getBody()->read(1024);

return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('response_to_return', $response_to_return);
```